# Norm of complex quotient on unit circle

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following problem, given $z\in\mathbb{C}$ so that $|z|=1$,
then what's the norm of:
$$
\frac{az+b}{\bar{b}z+a}
$$

I know there has to be some easy trick, also I guess the way it's formulated the norm should be $\left|\frac{a+b}{\bar{b}+a}\right|$ but I can't prove it.

PS: This formula is wrong, still there has to be some sort of simplication.

Comment: Are you sure about that formula? Isn't the denominator equal to $\overline bz+\overline a$?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, why?

Comment: $a=z=i, b=1$ is a counter-example to your claim.

Comment: It looks odd. That's all.

Comment: You cannot eliminate $z$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see, but there has to be some simplification.